# Exklusives und inklusives logisches "oder"

Tags: conjunction

Das logische "oder" bedeutet so viel wie "entweder A oder B oder (A und B)".

Wenn man im Deutschen jedoch sagt

> Ich gehe ins Kino oder in den Zoo.

meint man meistens

> Ich gehe entweder ins Kino oder in den Zoo.

Was kann man sagen, wenn man meint

> Ich gehe entweder ins Kino oder in den Zoo oder beides.

Wie kann man also im Deutschen kurz ein inklusives oder sagen? Ist das "oder" laut Duden überhaupt exklusiv / inklusiv?

Comment: Gibt es denn in anderen, gesprochenen Sprachen unterschiedliche Kurzformen für beide 'Oder'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/oder) lässt beide Bedeutungen zu:

> [oder]
>
> 1.a. drückt aus, dass von zwei oder mehreren Möglichkeiten jeweils nur eine als Tatsache zutrifft (ausschließend; vgl. entweder … oder);
> Abkürzung: od.
>
> 1.b. drückt aus, dass von zwei oder mehreren
> Möglichkeiten mindestens eine als Tatsache zutrifft (einschließend);
> Abkürzung: od.

Im Sprachgebrauch glaube ich allerdings, dass hier Verständlichkeit/Eindeutigkeit vor Kürze geht: Der Zusatz "...oder beides" ist auch gar nicht so wahnsinnig lang und vermeidet Missverständnisse.

Ich persönlich würde

> Ich gehe ins Kino oder in den Zoo.

eigentlich immer als "exklusives oder" verstehen.

**Edit:**

bernd_k hat mich noch auf einen anderen Gedanken gebracht: Die Intonation spielt eine Rolle. Er gibt die folgenden Fragen als Beispiel:

> Gehst Du ins Kino oder in den Zoo?
> Kommst du an einer Tankstelle oder
> einem Zeitungsladen vorbei?

Zuerst hätte ich gesagt, dass ich die Kino/Zoo-Frage exklusiv, die Zigarettenfrage inklusiv verstehen würde - dann fiel mir auf, dass es von der Satzmelodie abhängt:

Wenn die Frage exklusiv gemeint ist, werden die beiden Elemente stärker betont, wenn inklusiv, werden die beiden Elemente "gedehnt" (ich kann leider nicht besser ausdrücken, was ich meine - fällt jemandem eine bessere, präzisere Beschreibung ein?)

Interessanterweise dreht sich jetzt mein erster Eindruck um: Wenn ich jetzt beide Beispiele "inklusiv" betone, geht nur das Kino/Zoo-Beispiel in Richtung "echt inklusiv" - ich verstehe es dann so, dass danach gefragt wird, ob der Befragte vielleicht Aversionen gegen die beiden Möglichkeiten hat, oder Workaholic ist, oder ob er eben *grundsätzlich* auch mal in den Zoo oder ins Kino geht - oder beides :)
Bei der Zigarettenfrage spielt trotz "inklusiver Aussprache" die Einschließlichkeit keine Rolle: der Frager wäre wohl eher überrascht, wenn er Zigaretten von der Tanke *und* dem Zeitungsladen mitgebracht bekäme...

Insgesamt würde ich auch diese "oders" eher als "aufzählend" bezeichnen - es geht dem Frager weniger darum, die Möglichkeit "oder beides" auszudrücken, als vielmehr, dass es ihm egal ist, ob nur eine oder alle genannten Möglicheiten zutreffen.
Vielleicht wäre es bei "oder" im sprachlichen Bereich sinnvoller, nicht "exklusiv/inklusiv" zu unterscheiden, sondern vielmehr "streng exklusiv/aufzählend".

Comment: +1, ich wage zu behaupten, dass *die meisten* Menschen ein exklusives Oder meinen und sehr überrascht sind, wenn sie feststellen, dass ein logisches Oder eben inklusiv ist. Allerdings wird auch keiner überrascht sein, wenn der Beispielaussagende dann doch nach dem Zoo noch ins Kino gegangen ist.

Comment: Beamte: "Sie haben also ein Kind. Ist es ein Junge oder ein Mädchen?"       Logiker: "Ja"

Comment: Es hängt immer vom Kontext ab. Wenn ich in die Bäckerei gehe, und sage, ich hätte gerne '20 Körnerbrötchen - egal ob Mehrkorn~, Weltmeister~, Sesam~ oder Sonnenblumenbrötchen, dann würde ich mich nicht wundern einen Mix in der großen Tüte vorzufinden. Noch deutlicher: "Sie können die Pause nutzen um zu rauchen, oder die Toilette zu besuchen". Niemand würde erwarten, dass man jetzt nur eines darf, außer ich fügte an: "... aber nicht sowohl als auch."

Comment: @Mac Wie ist es mit 'Gehst du ins Kino oder in den Zoo?', 'Kommst du an einer Tankstelle oder einem Zeitungsladen vorbei?' dürfte auf jede Fall nicht exklusiv verstanden werden.

Comment: @bernd_k: Dürfte sehr wohl exclusiv verstanden werden, wenn beide wissen, dass nur auf dem Weg zum einen die Tankstelle, und auf dem Weg zum anderen der Zeitungsladen liegt, und aus dem äüßeren Kontext (Zeit inkl. Weg 2h für's Kino, und für den Weg zum Zoo, der in die Gegenrichtung liegt, alleine 30 Minuten).

Comment: @user unknown. Kann aber auch als 'kommst du irgendwo vorbei, wo du mir die Zeitschrift mitbringen kannst' verstanden werden.

Comment: Ja, ja, ich bestreite nicht, dass es nicht-exklusiv verstanden werden kann, nur dass es immer so verstanden werden muss. Ich meine, es ist immer vom Kontext abhängig, und meisst lassen sich spitzfindige Ausnahmen, und wieder Ausnahmen von den Ausnahmen finden.

Comment: @Georges Q: Wie viele Prolog-Programmierer braucht man, um eine Glühbirne auszuwechseln? A: Nein.

Comment: @ bernd_k +1 für das super Beispiel, das mich nochmal auf einen ganz anderen Gedanken gebracht hat. Danke!

Comment: @FUZxxl Ich muss leider zugeben, dass ich deinen Witz nicht verstehe. Hat er wirklich etwas mit Prolog, einer Programmiersprache von der ich nichts weiß, zu tun?

Comment: @Georges Nun, [Prolog](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog_(Programmiersprache)) ist eine logische Programmiersprache: Ein System, dass an Hand von gegebenen Fakten andere beweist und Lösungen finden kann, insbesondere sind Prädikate (Ausrücke die Wahrheitswerte zurückliefern) extrem wichtig. Da man in Prolog idR. nicht nach "wie viele", sondern nach "ist ..." fragt, Ist die Antwort natürlich "Nein".

Comment: Danke,FUZxxl. Das ist, wie oft mit guten Witzen, sehr lehrreich.

Comment: Mir fällt auf: Wenn ich ein inklusives oder meine, mache ich vor dem ersten Element der aufzählung eine Pause, spreche aber dafür die ganze Aufzählung inkl. oder recht schnell, und ohne besondere Betonung der einzelnen, insb. nachfolgenden Elemente: `Gehst du... insKinooderindenZoo?`. Ich setze also quasi im Kopf eine Klammer. Wenn es ein exklusives oder ist, mache ich nach dem ersten Element, also vor dem oder, eine kleine Pause: `Gehst du ins Kino - oder in den Zoo?`. Wahrscheinlich unterstütze ich das unbewusst noch mit leichter Gestik.

Answer (score 1):

Wie bereits erwähnt kann das deutsche »oder« laut Dudens Definition sowohl *exklusiv* als auch *inklusiv* sein. Leider gibt es kein deutsches Wort, welches nur eine der beiden Bedeutungen besitzt.

Apropos, in *technischen Kontexten* bzw. in der *Logik* werden die Symbole `⊕` und `+` für *exklusive* respektive *inklusive* Disjunktion verwendet.

#### exklusives Oder

Um ein exklusives „oder“ eindeutig auszudrücken verwende ich grundsätzlich die Kombination „entweder…oder“. Hiermit lässt sich sogar die Exklusivität der beiden Satzglieder zusätzlich unterstreichen, und zwar indem die Wörter „entweder“ und „oder“ – textuell in kursiver Schrift – betont werden.

#### inklusives Oder

Ein inklusives „oder“ eindeutig zu formulieren ist leider etwas schwieriger. Auf der [Wiktionary-Seite zum Wort »oder«](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/oder#oder_.28Deutsch.29) – Bedeutung `2a` – sind ein paar „Synonyme“ aufgelistet. Momentan sind das:

- beziehungsweise
- vielmehr
- besser gesagt
- respektive
- mit anderen Worten
- das heißt
- und/oder

Interessanterweise ist *und/oder* [im Duden aufgeführt](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/und_oder) und kann deshalb m. E. im informellen Kontext problemlos verwendet werden. In wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten lässt es sich jedoch im Zweifelsfall nicht vermeiden, den Satz umzuformulieren.

Answer (score 0):

Machmal wird "und/oder" benutzt.

Also: Ich gehe entweder ins Kino und/oder in den Zoo.

Aber ein eindeutiges einzelnes Wort kennt die natürliche Sprache im Deutschen nicht.

Comment: „entweder“ und „und/oder“ schließen sich aus. Mit „entweder“ wird immer ein exklusiver Oder eingeleitet, „und/oder“ ist aber immer inklusiv.